# Moving child GameObject inside moving parent GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a 2.5D SHMUP type game in which the world continuously moves forward while the player's spaceship and camera stay in place. This means that even if the world is moving, if the player's ship is in the middle of the screen it will stay there.

To do this I've created an empty game object named Moving World and attached the following script to it:

```
public class movingWorldController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float movementSpeed = 5f;

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I then added the camera and spaceship as children to of this object, and as a result they indeed move with the moving world object. However, I also have a script attached to the spaceship to allows it to move according to the player's input, and if I enable the script above the ship stops responding to the player's input. The ship's script looks like this:

```
public class ShipController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float moveSpeed = 5f;
    private Vector3 movement;

    void Update()
    {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        movement.z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

The ship controller works just fine when the world-moving script is disabled, so I suspect the world script is somehow overwriting the spaceship position. How may I solve this?

For a POC example see this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-fVjWgfUKn4&t=282s (jump to 4:00 to see the game in action). Note that in the video gamemaker is used to achieve the effect, while I am trying to achieve a similar effect using just code.

Comment: Does your parent have a rigidbody?

Comment: `localPosition`

Comment: @Menyus No. The parent doesn't have a rigidbody as it doesn't need to use the physics engine.

Comment: Is there a reason to make the camera & spaceship children of the background/obstacles? Just have the camera & spaceship be siblings of the rest of the world.

Comment: @Ruzihm In a SHMUP the background moves while the camera stays in place.  The spaceship can move within the constraints of one screen. I’ll add a video and some screenshots for reference later today.

Comment: Yes you've already explained you're doing a shmup but you still haven't explained why the camera or player should be children of `MovingWorld`

Comment: @Draco18s is right, you are using MovePosition, which uses world coordinates. rigidBodies are usually best left working without moving parents. This a problem for many different reasons. If you decided to have a moving world, I'm not sure why the spaceship needs to be a child of it. Place the camera as a child of the spaceship and move the ship inside the world, or move the world and keep the ship somewhat static.

Comment: Even in the official Unity [shmup tutorial](https://learn.unity.com/project/space-shooter-tutorial), the camera and player are top level game objects...

Comment: Thank you all for the comment. I've added more information to the question. Hopefully this helps you guys understand my situation better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved the effect I was aiming for by doing the following. First, I removed the `MovingWorld` object and instead applied the following script to the camera:

```
public class movingWorldController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float movementSpeed = 5f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.position = transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0, movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

This will cause the camera to continuously move forward. Next, to make sure the player's ship keeps up with the camera, and is maneuverable at the same time, I applied the following script to the ship's object:

```
public class ShipController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    private float shipVelocity = 5f;
    public float moveSpeed = 10f;
    private Vector3 movement;

   void Update()
   {
        movement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * moveSpeed;
        movement.z = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * moveSpeed + shipVelocity;
   }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + movement * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Two important notes:

- The `shipVelocity` variable was introduced to make sure the ship continues to cruise at camera-speed.
- Even though the camera is not a RigidBody its position update must occur during the `FixedUpdate` method to make sure it moves on the same frame as the ship. Updating it using the `Update` method will introduce jittering to the ship due to de-synchronization.